# Drupal incorrectly reporting that permissions need to be set on settings.php

Tags: 8, updating

I've updated a site to v8.5.3.  Checking the status report I have various messages.  One says:

> Not protected
> Protection disabled
>
> - The file sites/default/settings.php is not protected from modifications and
>   poses a security risk. You must change the file's permissions to be non-
>   writable.
> - The file sites/default/settings.local.php is not protected from
>   modifications and poses a security risk. You must change the file's
>   permissions to be non-writable.

I've checked these files and they are set to `444`, there are no write permissions set.  Drupal seems to be reporting this incorrectly.

Is there anything else I need to do or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They keyline here is `Protection disabled`.

Which means you have to check your `settings.php` or `setting.local.php` for

```
$settings['skip_permissions_hardening'] = TRUE;
```

which must be

```
$settings['skip_permissions_hardening'] = FALSE;
```

instead.

If it's not there already, add it.

Flush cache, done.

Comment: @user1532669 See also https://www.drupal.org/node/244924 for the definitive reference on file permissions and ownership.

Comment: Setting skip_permissions_hardening removes the warning, but that's not very intuitive at all. Why would you want to skip the check for permissions hardening? Don't you want Drupal to always tell you if those files don't have the correct permission at all times?

Comment: @Randell – It removes the warning because the permissions now get hardened. You want that to be skipped during development because you may need to edit these files more often.